# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to dbDataSet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dataset

I have an SQL database hosted on my localhost and I want to insert data into it from text boxes inside my form...

```
bDataSetTableAdapters.database_oneTableAdapter user = 
    new dbDataSetTableAdapters.database_oneTableAdapter();

dbDataSet.database_oneDataTable dt = 
    user.Register(
        usernameInput.Text, 
        textBox2.Text, 
        textBox3.Text, 
        textBox4.Text, 
        textBox6.Text);
```

However this returns the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to SystemSpeak.dbDataSet.database_oneDataTabe

Comment: It appears your Register method returns an int! If you use `int dt = user.Register(usernameInput.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox6.Text)` does the error go away?

Answer (score 0):

Your register method is returning the id of the new record that was just inserted.